# docker compose for asp.net core and mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to set up docker compose for asp.net core and mysql.

For docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
    xx-server:
        container_name: 'xx-server'
        image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim'
        restart: always
        working_dir: '/app'
        ports: 
            - "8888:80"
            - "8887:443"
        volumes: 
            - 'C:\Users\xx\netcoreapp3.1:/app'
        entrypoint: 
            ["dotnet", "xx.Web.Host.dll"]
        environment: 
            - "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+"
        depends_on: 
            - db
    db:
        container_name: 'db'
        image: 'mysql'
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydbname'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'mydbpd'
            MYSQL_USER: 'mydbuser'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'mydbpd'
        ports: 
          - "8885:3306"
        volumes: 
           - 'C:\Users\xx\mysql1:/var/lib/mysql'
```

And, I used connectionstring below in `appsettings.json`

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=db;port=8885;userid=mydbuser;pwd=mydbpd;database=mydbname"
  },
```

But, it always throw error that

```
An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. 
Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
```

After run `docker-compose up`, I could connect my db from mysql studio.

But, the asp.net core container always fail to connect mysql db.

Comment: Since your asp.net container has to reach the mysql container from within the docker network, the port mapping is pointless for the asp.net container. Does changing the port value in the connection string to `port=3306` solve your issue?

Comment: @octagon_octopus you saved my day, thanks a lot. It should go without port mapping.